# Ticks hitching a ride on a fly?

Tags: entomology, parasitism

Recently, my brother has been bothered by some particularly aggressive houseflies.

According to him, when these flies are squished, there is often a clacking noise, and then small arachnids come crawling off or out of the body (it's unclear which).

He recently managed to take pictures (see hereunder) where two of the things are in view, and I tentatively recognized them as ticks.

[image]
[image]

Apparently the clacking noise is produced when the arachnids are squished.
**Are these actually ticks ? And is this normal behaviour ?** I haven't managed to find anything about ticks hitching a ride on flies, but I don't have any other ideas.

If it helps, he lives in Brittany, in western France.

**Edit :** For scale, the fly in the pictures was a little below 1cm long

Comment: **Viewer discretion advised: The image above contains blood and violence** ;) Jokes aside, I haven't heard of ticks riding on flies, but I read that they can carry parasites such as pinworms, roundworms, hookworms and tapeworms.. Here is some more [info](https://www.insectary.com/portfolio-items/fly-parasites-for-fly-control/)

Comment: There are mites that ride on bumble bees.  https://www.bumblebeeconservation.org/bee-faqs/bumblebee-mites/

Comment: Do you have a scale on how big those are? Most mites are <1 mm across.

Comment: @bob1 the fly was a bit under 1cm, i'll edit the question to add this

Comment: @NinDjak - great, that makes these <1 mm, so they are likely to be mites.

Comment: What about seed ticks? They are very tiny as well. I am thinking flies can carry them.

Comment: These are not ticks. They're parasitic mites

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without a close up examination of the subjects, which would require microscope images or a decent macro image it is impossible to identify these creatures with any certainty to the level of species. With that in mind I will give an attempt at an answer.

These creatures are not ticks, they are almost certainly [mites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mite). Mites are of the subclass [Acari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acari) within the [Arachnida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arachnid) (spiders and scorpions also belong to this class). Ticks also belong in the Acari, so they are closely related to mites and quite similar morpholgically.

Mites are quite diverse, but generally less than 1 mm (0.039 inches) in length and are very diverse in what they feed on, ranging from being decomposers in the soil, to grazing algae in water, to feeding on plants and parasitising animals. As humans we have a particularly odd one (to me at least) called [Demodex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demodex) that lives in hair follicles, eating the sebaceous (oily) secretions and dead skin cells from around the hair.

For insects I believe (with no certainty, experts please weigh in) that the majority of mites are parasitic, feeding on the insects [hemolymph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemolymph) (blood equivalent for insects) by puncturing the seals at the joints in the exoskeleton. Incidentally, you can see some mites feeding on the legs of the crane-fly [in this SE Biology post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/101007/is-this-a-local-insect).

In the case of the OP we are likely looking at a parasitic mite of the common house fly (*Musca domestica*, which have left the now dead insect as their food source is no longer supplying food.

Flies do have a common mite species *[Macrocheles muscaedomesticae](https://academic.oup.com/aesa/article-abstract/54/6/776/175740)*, which is a mite that feeds on the eggs, and to some extent the larvae of the house fly and several other species of fly, and may also be associated with a range of other insects (see Biology Ecology sections [here](https://www.gbif.org/species/4549259)). The mite is found world-wide and is believed to be distributed on the adult flies. It is [uncertain if the mite actually attaches to the adult fly](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10493-019-00431-y) while it is being carried.

There are several species in the *Macrocheles* genus, which all parasitise in a similar manner to *M muscaedomesticae*. There are also a [few other species of mites that seem to parasitise house flies](https://academic.oup.com/ee/article-abstract/17/2/320/375585), including *[Poecilochirus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poecilochirus)* species, but these are less species-specific as far as I can tell.

Comment: A very thorough answer, thank you ! Since your mention of mites in the comments i've also found references to [mites being used for house fly control in livestock farms](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0032579119523008) , so this definitely checks out.
I doubt there's much more to add, and the question's been open for a few days, so I'll mark this as accepted answer.