# Is this a local insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

The monster below got into my house today (west of Paris, France). It is about 3 cm (1.2 inches) long.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have no idea if this is a local insect that I would then let free, or some invasive species I will kill (we have from time to time alerts about invasive insect species (especially mosquitoes) that put in danger the local ones)

Comment: Incidentally it looks like it has a couple of parasitic mites on its legs

Comment: @bob1: ah, I thought that was dust (she spent sometime in the house)

Comment: I don't think those are parasitic mites - I think they are pseudoscorpions - maybe hitching a ride to new homes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no expertise in (French) insects, but this looks like it might be a [crane fly (family: Tipulidae)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crane_fly) in the genus [*Ctenophora*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctenophora_(fly)).  The larvae of these flies feed on decaying wood, so a lack of (partially) dead trees or other dead wood in your vicinity would suggest this is not correct.

The hunched-back with long legs are suggestive of the crane-fly family and the V-shaped groove on the back more-or-less connecting the wing-bases is (according to the wikipedia article) characteristic of this family.

In particular, this looks quite similar to many pictures online of the Cone-horn cranefly [(*Ctenophora pectinicornis*)](https://gardensafari.net/en_picpages/ctenophora_pectinicornis.htm), which is [found in your area](https://www.gbif.org/species/5064369)

[image: Ctenophora pectinicornis]
[Image by Margaret McLoughlin](https://www.naturespot.org.uk/species/ctenophora-pectinicornis).

My understanding is that the simple antennae indicate that this is a female — males have feathery antennae.

Comment: Crane fly was my thought too. Looks like a case of mimicry with a wasp/bee as well.