# What insect is this? (Switzerland)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I took these photos in June in Zurich, Switzerland. The insect struck me as fairly large; I'd say the body was probably 2-3 cm long unless my memory is playing tricks on me. It sat just like this on a paved road. When I got close to take photos, it froze completely and I could take photos for minutes without it so much as twitching. Whenever I was farther from it, it would turn and walk a bit, but it seemed in no hurry to go anywhere.

[image: Unknown insect]

[image: Unknown insect]

Comment: See also [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/101007/46609).

Comment: Ah, yes. The differences in the antennae compared to some photos I could find threw me off; turns out that just means she's female. I think that's very likely a Ctenophora ornata.